# Excel VBA copying rows that do not appear in two arrays and do not have a certain value

Tags: excel, autofilter, vba

I would like to copy only those rows, whose value in column 1 do not appear in two separate arrays and whose value in column 3 = 0.

For example, my data looks like this:

```
Name ID flag

Alice 1232 0

Alice 885  0

Alice 8332 1

Bob  993  1

Dan 9932  0

Chet 12  1

Fiona  993 0
```

Array1 = (Bob, Fiona)

Array2 = (Dan)

So I don't wanna copy Dan, Fiona and Bob. Of the remaining, only the first two entries of ALice have 0 in the third column, so I want to copy and paste to a new sheet

```
Name ID flag

Alice 1232 0

Alice 885  0
```

I would like to do an Autofilter but my Arrays have 2000 to 4000 elements in them and I cannot to a Array11 = (<>Bob, <>Fiona) and so on.

I have an array of all names , say ArrayAll = (Alice, Bob, Chet, Dan, Fiona) but I don't know how to do set theory operations that would subtract Array1 and Array2 from ArrayAll, short of doing two long loops which will be super slow.

Right now, instead of Filtering and copying, I am copying everything and then Autofiltering and deleting based on the two arrays and the third condition. The problem is that my code is super super super slow.

```
  Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws1 = wb1.Worksheets("SCL_FL")
'    strSearch = "SCL_FL"
           With ws1
               .AutoFilterMode = False
               lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                With .UsedRange
            'Set copyFrom = .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow
                    Set copyFrom = .EntireRow
               End With
              .AutoFilterMode = False
           End With
            Set ws3 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
            With ws3
               If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
                  lRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                          After:=.Range("A1"), _
                          Lookat:=xlPart, _
                          LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                          SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                          SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                          MatchCase:=False).Row
              Else
                  lRow = 1
              End If
              copyFrom.Copy .Range("A1")
             .Name = "Rest"
             .AutoFilterMode = False
             .UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=Array2()
             .UsedRange.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
             .AutoFilterMode = False
             .AutoFilterMode = False
             .UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=Array1()
             .UsedRange.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
             .AutoFilterMode = False
             .AutoFilterMode = False
             .UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=Exceptions_Column, Criteria1:="1", Operator:=xlFilterValues
             .UsedRange.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
             .AutoFilterMode = False

           End With
```

Can someone please recommend a fast way to do this. Thank you!!

Comment: which part of your macro do you want to improve? Have you done any tests which part is the slowest?

Comment: @mehow I want to improve the part where I first copy, then paste, and then autofilter and delete (as opposed to autofiltering first and then copying and pasting.) The rest of my code (not posted here), was pretty fast (2-3 minutes) before I added this bit and now it's 30-40 minutes. I have a 3.2GB RAM computer. I don't know how to test which part of a code is slowest. Perhaps you can teach me how.

Comment: I have answered with a way I'd go about it. Please have a look and see if this is of any help to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amatya, if I understand correctly you want to improve the part which gets you all the results with `0`s only.

In that case I suggest first copying the sheet and then filtering it like this

```
Option Explicit

Sub Main()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    AddWorksheet
    FilterResults
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Private Sub AddWorksheet()
    Sheets(1).Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = "Working Copy"
End Sub

Private Sub FilterResults()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    lastRow = ws.Range("C" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = ws.Range("A1:C" & lastRow)

    ' filter and delete all but header row
    With rng
        .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="<>0"
        .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    End With

    ws.AutoFilterMode = False
End Sub
```

In a new workbook I set up a sample data like this (*on a `Sheet1`*)

[image]

then ran the code and got a new sheet at the end called *`"Working Copy"`* with the following results

[image]

Note: to be fair, I do not know of a faster way to filter results. I created a new sheet instead of copy - pasting ranges which is much slower. Then applied the filter which removed all rows that their 3rd column ( column C ) is not equal to 0.

This run super fast < under 1 second but if you have more data then I understand it may be a bit slower - not much though :)

It took 1 second with 10,000 rows so it's still pretty fast

Comment: thanks for your answer. I didn't do a good job explaining the problem. The issue is not just the filtering where the last ceolumn =0 but also in addition when the First column entries "don't belong" to two large arrays. I need to run all three filters in a fast way.

Comment: `xOr` operator wouldn't help?

Comment: oh  .. VBA autofilter has a NOR operator!! Awesome!! You rock!! Let me try and see if it is faster. I am guessing you mean NOR as opposed to exclusive OR. I think NOR will work rather than XOR. Thanks!!

Comment: @Amatya see [the operators](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/autofilter-vba-criteria.htm) you can use with the filter

Comment: So it seems that it only has the OR operator. I am not sure how  that would help me since I am not able to place an "<>" inside my array next to all the elements.

Comment: @Amatya yes, this has been asked multiple times. You need to build an array with all the data, remove the data youre not interested in from the array and then use that array as the filter.

Comment: thanks. I am looking on the website but if you can link a discussion/question then that would be great.